# Simple approx. formula for Inverse of the Logarithmic integral function

Tags: nt.number-theory

A pretty good simple approx. formula for inverse of the Logharitmic integral function  is:  
 $li^{-1}(x)\approx -\frac{1}{li(\frac{1}{x})}$  
  It is also an acurate approx. for the n-th prime number  
 $p_n \approx  -\frac{1}{li(\frac{1}{n})}$.   
Table ( integer parts ) :

$n\qquad\qquad 10\qquad 10^2\qquad\quad 10^3\qquad\quad 10^4\quad\qquad 10^5\qquad\qquad 10^6$

$li^{-1}(n)\qquad 20\quad 488\qquad 7762\qquad 104270\qquad 1298170\qquad 15479100$

$-\frac{1}{li(\frac{1}{n})}\quad 30\qquad 546\qquad 7803\qquad 101264\qquad 1244281\qquad 14755260$

$p_n\qquad\quad 29\qquad 541\qquad 7919\qquad 104729\qquad 1299709\qquad 15485863$ 
Is this approx. usefull and how to estimate the error $p_{n}-(-\frac{1}{li(\frac{1}{n})})$ ? Is it allways positive for big enough $n$?

Comment: inverse formulas in terms of elementary functions are at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/804107/87355 --- I presume these would be more useful than an inverse formula in terms of a special function; a representation in terms of the Lambert W-functions is at https://mathoverflow.net/q/278626/11260

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate large-$x$ approximation of $\text{Li}^{-1}(x)$, and containing only elementary functions, is
$$g(x)=x \left(\frac{\ln (\ln x)-2}{\ln x}+\ln x+\ln (\ln x)-1\right),$$
see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html

I compare these approximations in the table below (all entries are rounded to the nearest integer).

| function | p=4 | p=5 | p=6 | p=7 | p=8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\text{Li}^{-1}(10^p)$ | $104270$ | $1298172$ | $15479066$ | $179415191$ | $2038024425$ |
| $g(10^p)$ | $104546$ | $1299492$ | $15486599$ | $179464275$ | $2038374432$ |
| $-1/\text{Li}(1/10^p)$ | $101264$ | $1244281$ | $14755261$ | $170652555$ | $1937361573$ |

Comment: I am acquainted with this approx. and other approx. with elementary functions, but I thinck that $li^{-1}(x)\approx -\frac{1}{li(\frac{1}{x})}$ is interesting on its own, because of the simple agebraic connection betwen $li^{-1}(x)$ and the original Logaritmic integral function.